# Need to write values to a file based on loop in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a correlation which extracts time and reference id from the response, but the number of matches are more than 2000. I want to write all these 2000 matches to a file. For this, I know that I need to do something like this (screenshot attached). Require help in completing the code

Values - Name of the correlation (Regex extractor - screenshot)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't ever inline [JMeter Functions or variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into scripts, I think your code will start working if you replace `${Values_matchNr}` with `Integer.parseInt(vars.get("Values_matchNr"))`
2. Get familiarized with [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) functions as your code is syntactically incorrect and it doesn't make any sense as variables will be overwritten on the next loop
3. Don't use Beanshell for scripting, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be going for JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). The equivalent Groovy code would be something  like:

   ```
   1.upto(vars.get('Values_matchNr') as int, { i ->
       new File('values.txt') << vars.get('Values_' + i + '_g1') << ',' << vars.get('Values_' + i + '_g2') << System.getProperty('line.separator')
   })
   ```

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter